# Evento cuando usuario concede permisos a pagina web

Tags: javascript, jquery, permisos, eventos

Reciban un cordial saludo.
Necesito detectar cuando un usuario concede permisos a una página web. En mi caso la página solicita permisos de camara y microfono ya que es un videochat, y necesito detertar cuando el usuario concedio los permisos. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Desde el `backend` tienes más permisos que puedes combinar, desde `Componentes > Jevents > configuración > Permisos`, tienes por ejemplo el de editar eventos o editar eventos propios , ver imagen

Verifica que todos los permiso para tu sito web  de operaciones en tu instalación (se muestra en `Cuenta > pestaña Permiso`). 
Espero te ayude.

Comment: Gracias pero creo que no fui claro en mi pregunta. Me disculpo. Necesito saber si existe una forma de detectar el evento de conceder los permisos desde javascript o jquery para ejecutar un permiso

Answer (score 0):

Para que el usuario final, según el flujo *natural* para este tipo de casos, use su micrófono y cámara, es necesario que *se le invite* a ello. Esto desplegará un pequeño diálogo preguntándole al usuario si quiere o no usar los dispositivos solicitados.

```
navigator
.mediaDevices
.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: true,
})
.then(onPermissionsAccept)
.catch(onPermissionsReject);
```

En la función `onPermissionsAccept` ejecutas el código que deseas se ejecute cuando el usuario presione *"Permitir"* y en la función `onPermissionsReject` cuando presione *"Rechazar"*.

```
function onPermissionsAccept() {
  // hacer o mostrarle algo al usuario
}
```